# Mongoose returning Object not Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've struggling trying to make my mongoose query return an array, since I need to:

1. Find 0..N docs from one collection;
2. Save this found array in another nested doc collection;

My code:

```
CarIndex.find({ '_id': { $in: ids } }, 'carID carBrand carModel location')
            .then(collections => {
                const out = []

                collections.map( (doc) => {
                    const {carID ,carBrand ,carModel ,location} = doc
                    const car = {carID ,carBrand ,carModel ,location};
                    out.push(car)
                })

                console.log(out)
                console.log(out.length)
                console.log(typeof out)

                return CarCollection.findOneAndUpdate({ '_id': collectionId }, { $addToSet: { carCollection: { $each: { out } } } })
            });
```

The output error:

> [04/01/2018 11:04:48.980] [LOG]

```
[ { carID: 'd82e41b0-f14f-11e7-b845-990cb852c2b3',
    carBrand: 'Peugeot',
    carModel: '207 Sed. Passion XR Sport 1.4 Flex 8V 4p',
    location: [-23.539727799999998,-46.5111749] },
  { carID: 'd82f2c10-f14f-11e7-b845-990cb852c2b3',
    carBrand: 'Nissan',
    carModel: 'Sentra 2.0/ 2.0 Flex Fuel 16V Mec.',
    location: [-23.607240972099525,-46.72912079051677] } ]
```

> [04/01/2018 11:04:48.982] [LOG]   2
>
> [04/01/2018 11:04:48.983] [LOG]   object
>
> [04/01/2018 11:04:48.997] [ERROR] MongoError: The argument to $each in
> $addToSet must be an array but it was of type object

Comment: But here `console.log(out)` is an array so what is the issue

Comment: Actually it is not, if you check the 3rd log, it shows `object`, leading to the error! Thanks

Comment: in javascript everything is Object array is also Object. you can check like this `out instanceof Array`

Comment: Hmm good catch, but why can't I save it using the $addToSet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this

```
 CarIndex.find({ '_id': { $in: ids } }, 'carID carBrand carModel location')
                .then(collections => {
                    const out = []

                    collections.map( (doc) => {
                        const {carID ,carBrand ,carModel ,location} = doc
                        const car = {carID ,carBrand ,carModel ,location};
                        out.push(car)
                    })

                    console.log(out)
                    console.log(out.length)
                    console.log(typeof out)

                    return CarCollection.findOneAndUpdate({ '_id': collectionId }, { $addToSet: { carCollection: { $each: out  } } })
                });
```